# Контроль вечного цикла, через input()

Tags: python, циклы, input

Допустим у меня есть некий код с бесконечным(не обязательно). Сам пользователь не участвует, в внутреннем действии самого цикла. Мне нужно сделать, так что-бы User, когда захотел смог написать команду через 'input()' и остановить цикл. Но если просто добавить внутрь цикла input() с условием и т.д. То цикл будет останавливаться пока пользователь не введет что-либо. А мне надо что-бы когда захотел, тогда и написал. При этом возможность у тебя была всегда.

Comment: Завести два потока, один с циклом, другой с input

Comment: Я новичок и плохо понимаю, что для этого нужно. В интернете довольно странные и сложные примеры. Можете объяснить пожалуйста!

Comment: Гугли `kbhit python` - a [вот такое](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18672923/4928642) нашёл, если у тебя винда, то может подойти.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

run = True

def worker():
    while run:
        print('.', end='', flush=True)
        sleep(1)


Thread(target=worker).start()

while run:
    if input() == 'quit':
        run = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - просто прервать его с помощью обычного `Ctrl+C`

```
def do_something():
    print('процесс идет')
    time.sleep(2)

fl = True

try:
    while fl:
        do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Вы нажали Ctrl+C, процесс завершен.')
    fl = False


процесс идет
процесс идет
процесс идет
процесс идет
Вы нажали Ctrl+C, процесс завершен.
```

Answer (score -3):

Есть много способов. Обьясню на самом простом примере.
В условие каждого новое input() добавить условие "stop", при котором цикл будет останавливаться.
Пример использования:

```html
a = True
b = ""
while (a == True):
  input(b)
  if (b == "стоп"):
    a = False
  else:
    print("а Трушная переменная")
```

Comment: А если вопрос прочитать?

Comment: Мне нужно, что-бы пользователь мог даже не прикосаться к клавиатуре, а цикл бы шел. И лишь когда он захотел мог ввести команду и цикл остановился

Comment: В вашем примере неправильное использование `input`, и ответ не решает проблему из вопроса. Чтобы получить результат из `input` нужно приравнять какую-либо переменную к этой функции, а передача аргумента внутрь нее - это совершенно другое. В вашем примере, что бы пользователь ни ввел `b` всегда будет равно `""`