# Как можно в Python пропустить sys.stdin.read(), если нечего читать?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я так понимаю, что если указатель находится в конце файла, то на `file.read()` программа остановится и будет ожидать пока там что-то не появится.

Во всяком случае именно так ведет себя программа при чтении из `stdin`.

Можно ли как-то избежать такого поведения? Например, перед чтением из файла (в моем случае `stdin`) проверить есть ли там что читать.

## Дополнение

В моем конкретном случае мне нужно проверить, нажата ли пользователем клавиша и, если нет, выполнение программы должно продолжаться, если есть, то я читаю код клавиши и отправляю его в UART.

Comment: STDIN отличается от обычного файла тем, что у него в общем случае нет EOF (End Of File). `EOF` появляется только если ввести комбинацию `Ctrl+Z`. В общем, будет полезнее если вы более обширно опишите вашу задачу...

Comment: @MaxU дополнил!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pynput/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python

Comment: Смотрите в сторону функции select() или poll(). Так зовуться вызовы ОС, в питоне наверняка есть интерфейс для них

Comment: `is_pressed`, как я понял, может использоваться только для проверки нажатия *конкретной* клавиши?

Comment: @MaxU, по моему `Ctrl+D`  :-)

Comment: @MarianD, по-моему, все-таки `Ctrl+Z` :-)

Comment: @MaxU, у меня в консоли Windows работает «ваша» комбинация (`Ctrl+Z`), в консоли и терминале Linux «моя» комбинация (`Ctrl+D`), в PyCharm под Windows и в IDLE Питона под Windows тоже «моя». :-)

Comment: Чтение файлов так себя не ведёт, это только у stdin так

Comment: Вариант с ожиданием нажатия клавиши в другом потоке не подходит?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо за идею! Я многопоточным программированием не владею. Видимо это хороший повод его изучить ;)

Comment: @RomanMatveev можете посмотреть примеры в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/932140/204271) и [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847563/204271) ответах.